# Spring @WebMvcTest fails with @PreAuthorize controller classes generated by openapi-generator-maven-plugin

Tags: spring, spring-boot, openapi-generator, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

I'm using the `org.openapitools:openapi-generator-maven-plugin:7.0.1` to generate the controllers and request/response objects in a Spring Boot 3 project. This basically works fine but I have a problem with the security conifguration.

I'm overriding the `*Delegate` class generated by the plugin like this:

```java
@RestController
public class PingController implements PingApiDelegate {

    @Override
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ping')")
    public ResponseEntity<String> ping() {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body("pong");
    }
}
```

As you can see in the following configuration class, all requests are authenticated by default and `@EnableMethodSecurity` is set to use the `@PreAuthorize` annotation.

**RestSecurityConfiguration**

```java
@Configuration
@EnableMethodSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class RestSecurityConfiguration {

    private final JwtAuthConverter jwtAuthConverter;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        return httpSecurity
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(httpRequests -> httpRequests.anyRequest().authenticated())
                .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2ResourceServerCustomizer -> oauth2ResourceServerCustomizer.jwt(jwtCustomizer -> jwtCustomizer.jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwtAuthConverter)))
                .sessionManagement(sessionManagementCustomizer -> sessionManagementCustomizer.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .build();
    }
}
```

When testing the controller with a `@WebMvcTest`, then I get a HTTP 401 instead of 403 when the passed role does not match. The same test passes if I made the following changes:

- Remove `@EnableMethodSecurity` and `@PreAuthorize`
- Adding `httpRequests.requestMatchers("/api/ping").hasRole("ping")`

---

```java
@WebMvcTest(PingController.class)
@Import({PingApiController.class})
class PingControllerTest extends AbstractControllerTest {

    @Test
    void should_return_pong() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/api/ping")
                        .with(authentication(defaultAuthentication("wrong-role"))))
                .andExpect(status().isForbidden());
    }

    protected static Authentication defaultAuthentication(String... authorities) {
        Jwt jwt = Jwt.withTokenValue("token")
                .header("alg", "none")
                .claim("email", "foo@example.com")
                .build();
        final List<String> rolePrefixedAuthorities = Arrays.stream(authorities).map(authority -> "ROLE_" + authority).toList();
        return new JwtAuthenticationToken(jwt, AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList(rolePrefixedAuthorities));
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your test look like.

Comment: Upated my question with an example test (I must not post the complete code here).

Comment: Try `@EnableMethodSecurity(proxyTargetClass=true)`. You are implementing an interface which can lead to interface proxies which can hide certain information like annotations.

Comment: That's a good point. Unfortunately, the behavior hasn't changed.

Comment: Maybe it's noteworthy that my test class is annotated with `@Import({ApiChangeApiController.class)` because otherwise it won't find the default path and gives a 404.

Comment: I have no idea what that imported class does.

Comment: It's the default implementation of the controller generated by the OpenAPI plugin from the specification.

Comment: I have a love/hate relationship with code generators, it generally breaks more then it solves in my opinion. BUt alas, I did ask for you r test class. What do you have in `@WebMvcTest`?

Comment: I agree on your view about code generators. I added the example test in the original question.

Comment: Why does your `@WebMvcTest` point to your test class?| It should point to the controller you want to test such that it can be scanned and Spring BOot knows what to bootstrap. You are shoehorning this (partially) in again with the `@Import`. Instead you should have `@WebMvcTest(PingApiController.class)`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255636/discussion-between-robert-strauch-and-m-deinum).